# How to organize integration tests using maven?

Tags: java, maven, junit, integration-testing

There are two separated projects: client and server. How can I test client-server interaction properly? Is there a simple solution to do it using maven?

This is how I do:

1) I've got a junit test that runs client and server in different threads. I use `@BeforeClass` to start client/server and `@AfterClass` to stop.

2) I run all the tests including unit tests using `mvn test`

Is it ok to run client and server in one process? Do I have to divide unit and integration tests?

Comment: Please fill in some more detail. Is there a particular framework you're using (Spring, Jersey)? How are the projects "separated"? What sort of communication are you trying to test (custom protocol, JMS, HTTP)?

Comment: I don't use Spring or Jersey. Communication between modules are self made.

Comment: Oof. That's going to complicate things (because you can't use standard tools to test each end). Still provide more detail about that communication.

Comment: well by its definition I will argue: yes. Tests that tests the interaction between client and server are integration-tests. They go beyond that "unit" you focus on in pure unit tests. If you can fire up the server within the test that is fine. I would rename them end let them execute by the failsafe plugin (mvn integration-test or mvn verify). There are pre- and post-integration-test phases where a server could be started too. In the end this just changes the names of you test-classes. But for a compatible meaning with the rest of the world I would recommend doing it.